# ADF Pipeline Export and Rename Mult files

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have multiple folders with dynamic names in Azure Storage Explorer. Each folder has 3 files (A.csv, B.csv, and C.csv). How do you Export A.csv and B.csv from each folder into another folder and append the last modified date to the file name i.e. A012523.csv for last modified date 01-25-2023 using an ADF pipeline?

I used a metadata task to get the child items. I used a filter to get the folders that begin with xxx and end with zip.. The folders are unzipped. I used a foreach loop to loop through each folder. In the foreach loop I used a metadata task to get the item name and last modified. I used a copy task outside the foreach loop to copy the A.csv file from each folder to another azure storage explorer folder. In the copy task I used the wildcard file path srcfolder/file*.zip/A.csv for the source. The sink has a FileName @variables('LastModified'). The sink dataset has a FileName parameter with Adestfolder/@dataset().FileName as the file path.

I'm expecting only the renamed csv files in Adestfolder, but it's copying each folder with A.csv to the destination folder without renaming the file.
A012523.csv
A020823.csv
A051023.csv

Answer (score 0):

As you have only 3 files(`A.csv`,`B.csv`,`C.csv`) in every source folder, you can try like below.

After filtering the folder names give that to a ForEach activity. Inside ForEach, create **3 pairs of `Get Meta data activity -> Copy activity`** (for 3 files in each folder) with dataset parameters.

**Get Meta data activity:**

Give the dataset with parameter for file name (Give the path till the Main source folder in the dataset path).

`@concat(item().name,'/A.csv')`

[image]

Then, add the copy activity to it. Use the same dataset(`csv_file`) and same expression as above for the source of the copy activity.

For sink of the copy activity, use another dataset with parameter for file name.

```
Adestfolder/@{concat('A', formatDateTime(activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified, 'MMddyy'), '.csv')}
```

[image]

Do the same for `B.csv` and `C.csv`.

**My Pipeline JSON for reference:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "sourcecsv",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Filter1",
                "type": "Filter",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "condition": {
                        "value": "@and(startswith(item().name, 'File'), endswith(item().name,'.zip'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Filter1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Filter1').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata2",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "csv_file",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@concat(item().name,'/A.csv')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "lastModified"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata2_copy1",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "csv_file",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@concat(item().name,'/B.csv')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "lastModified"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata2_copy2",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "csv_file",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@concat(item().name,'/C.csv')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "lastModified"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata2",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "csv_file",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@concat(item().name,'/A.csv')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "sinkcsv",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "Adestfolder/@{concat('A', formatDateTime(activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified, 'MMddyy'), '.csv')}",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data2",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata2_copy1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "csv_file",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@concat(item().name,'/B.csv')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "sinkcsv",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "Adestfolder/@{concat('B', formatDateTime(activity('Get Metadata2_copy1').output.lastModified, 'MMddyy'), '.csv')}",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data3",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata2_copy2",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "csv_file",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@concat(item().name,'/C.csv')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "sinkcsv",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "Adestfolder/@{concat('C', formatDateTime(activity('Get Metadata2_copy2').output.lastModified, 'MMddyy'), '.csv')}",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Result files after Pipeline Execution:**

[image]

If you have more than the above fixed files in the folders, then you need to use another loop inside ForEach. As nested loops are not supported in ADF, you can try with calling another pipeline with loop by passing this file paths.